# javascript passing variables from a method with a loop to a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

basically I'm trying to pass a variable that is defined in a JSON array that is parsed through in a for loop to be accessible in a click statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getJSON();
  var usedID;
 });
 function readJSON() {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.array.length; i ++) {
  usedID = json.array[i].id;
  var template = $('repeaterTemplate').clone();
  template.removeAttr('id');
  template.attr('id', 'k' + json.array.id);
  var omega = json.array.id;        
  $('#repeater').append(template);
  (function(o) {
     $('#' + o).click(function() {
    // this is where the submitID click function is now. It passes the omega value in

  });
  })(omega);

 }
 }
 $('.submitID').click(function() {
    submitNow(usedID);
  }
```

Right now I have the submitID click function in my for loop and it's causing the submitNOW function to be called however many times the loop cycles through.  Can anyone help me with passing the userID from the readJSON() to the click function?

I'm getting a parse error with your each function:

```
var userID = [];
var j = 0;
$('.submitNOW').each(function() {
   function(id) {
$(this).click(function() {
  submitNow(id);
});
  }(userID[j]);
});
```

Comment: so you want each `.submitID` element to call `submitNow` with a different value for `userID`? or the same value for all of them?

Comment: You may want to look into using jQuery's 'each' method for iterating over the data, it will reduce some of the loop boilerplate you've got there.

Comment: You are getting `usedID` values inside the for loop. So, multiple IDs are expected. Which one do you want to pass?

Comment: -lincolnk, yeah I need different values of UserID. The correct value is chosen when a click action is made on a specific list item

Comment: -Josh, can you give me an example? I've never really gotten the hang of the each method

Comment: -sandeepan I need to pass the userID that corresponds with the div that is clicked on. I'll update my code

Comment: @fordays if you can provide a little more details. Is getJSON() your own defined function? How do chose the correct value? Do you read  `id` attribute of the `.submit` element which is clicked?

Comment: @fordays how are you identifying which div gets which user id? in your example you're attaching a handler to non-unique elements.

Comment: I updated my code to show you whats going on.

Comment: @fordays First tell me what does this do? `(function(o) {  })(omega);` I am stuck here. I have never used this kind of thing...

Comment: @fordays you're referencing `json.array.id` without an indexer- should it be `json.array[i].id`?

Comment: @sandeepan that's a self-invoking method- it's defined and then immediatly called with `omega` as the parameter. it's used for preserving the value of a variable inside a loop.

Comment: @lincolnk yeah I forgot to put the index variables in to cycle through the json properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this but you don't have any way to associate a specific user id with a specific element.

this example gives user id's in the order they are encountered to `.submitID` elements in the order that they are encountered. it also assumes there are the same number of user id's and elements.

```
/* this is a non-working example */

var usedIDs = [];

function readJSON() {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.array.length; i++) {
        usedIDs.push(json.array[i].id);
        moreFunctions();
        moreStuff();
    }
}

var j = 0;

$('.submitID').each(function () {

    function (id) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            submitNow(id);
        });
    }(usedIDs[j]);

    j++;

});
```

edits: based on your post revision this is my best guess at what you are trying to do.

```
function readJSON() {

    for (var i = 0; i < json.array.length; i++) {

        var usedID = json.array[i].id;

        var template = $('repeaterTemplate').clone();
        template.removeAttr('id');
        template.attr('id', 'k' + usedID);
        $('#repeater').append(template);

        (function (o) {
            // assumign template is a jQuery object here; if not use $(template) instead
            template.click(function () {
                // this is where the submitID click function is now. It passes the omega value in 
                submitNow(o);
            });
        })(usedID);

    }
}
```

Comment: hey, look at my code example up top. I'm getting a parse error with your example each function

Comment: @fordays missing `)` before `(userID[j]);` keep your cool! :)